# tracking a subway map

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

let's say i want to build a smartphone app that tells a user when/where to get off a subway station.  i can think of two ways of doing this:

1) using GPS and map of the subway routes, track the location of the user and notifies him when the destination is reached
2) have him press start when he gets on a train as the train starts (which may not be realistic because the user could simply forget to do this), use the known travel time from starting station to end station, and simply notifies him when the time is up.

can someone tell me if there are any other good approaches?  thanks.

Comment: A service like this must be reliable.  Without a clear view of the southern sky, you don't have GPS, so that's out.  Measuring start and end times is out too.  Even if you had a proper data feed that was updated live, you still have the issue of update problems and lack of cell service in most tunnels.  Simply guessing on start/end times is nowhere near reliable enough for this.  Honestly the best way to make this work is to alert the user which station to watch for.

Comment: can you elaborate on how to alert user which station to watch for?  for example, the user selects the destination station, and every 2 minutes the subway map would flash on the screen with the destination station blinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to go with 'dead reckoning'. Basically, dead reckoning is a navigation technique that uses a confirmed starting location plus accurate velocity and time to calculate a new location. Keep in mind that velocity is itself a combination of heading and speed and that the heading must be a true heading. In an airplane, compass heading would have to be combined with wind speed and direction to get a true heading. I don't think you have to account for drift on a subway, but you will have to account for varying device orientation as the user moves around or uses the device itself. Also, just because heading is normally a compass bearing doesn't mean that it has to be. You may be able to get the job done using only the accelerometers and a timer.

Proper use of dead-reckoning also requires frequent 'resets' to known locations as you reach them so that errors can't add up too badly. For this application, I would argue that curve- and stop-detection can be used as resets. You may get false positives for 'service' stops that are too close to real stops, but those may be rare enough to ignore. In fact, if it wasn't the exit stop, it might not matter because you might still be accurate enough for the next-stop warning and if was the exit stop, it won't matter because the ride is over.

To summarize: you need to be sure that you have a good initial starting point; you need to compensate for device reorientation to get true heading; you need to know your average speed between heading changes and the time-on-heading to calculate distance-on-heading. You can improve overall accuracy by resetting at known landmarks.

Edit: I don't know if this gets you any closer to the answer, but Chris Stratton raised an interesting point about summing the accelerometer vectors. Is it possible to track the orientation of the device accurately enough to have a reliable orientation-independent gravity vector? Can you keep that out of your vector sum? Can that provide a useful acceleration along a useful orientation-independent vector? If so, then tracking the duration of the acceleration will get you an average speed for that duration and a final speed for the end of acceleration. Absent acceleration, the speed will remain constant. Putting that all together might pile inaccuracy on top of inaccuracy to the point of uselessness.

Comment: You don't have anything remotely approaching a usable speed metric.  Integrating the accelerometers isn't going to give you anything useful.  With a lot of luck you might be able to detect a bump at each rail joint, but still pretty farfetched.

Comment: @Chris Stratton: Yeah, I have no idea whether it's practical to use acceleration and duration to come up with a speed. It might be possible if the device was completely fixed to to the train, but trying to sort out the vectors in a handheld device would give me a headache. Still, so many things give me a headache that I thought it was at least mentioning dead reckoning.

Answer (score 2):

If the subway line has cellular service (some that were going to had it turned off on security concerns) you might be able to do something with network location.

You could use the accelerometer to try to detect and count station stops - but trains stop in between stations from time to time due to delays ahead.  Also battery life would be reduced.  EDIT: realized you won't be able to tell acceleration from deceleration as you have no idea of orientation (unless you find the compass sensor workable in that environment) - you could only see that the vector sum of the three accelerometers was greater than gravity for a period of seconds.

You could try to use the microphone to detect the sounds of train motors and brakes (some are extremely characteristic) but that has the same problem with battery life and unscheduled stops between stations.  Not to mention scheduled stations bypassed for repair work.

Perhaps you should give the user a scrollable list of stations marking the journey and let them keep track.

Comment: can you elaborate on how to use a scrollable list of stations?  again, blinking dots on a map?

Comment: No map, make a vertical list of stations on a single line, from the start to the end of the journey (portion on that line).  Often such a list is posted on a platform or horizontally in a car with lights that turn on as each station is passed.  But in a city such as NY you are going to have to be plugged into notifications of service changes, as stations can be bypassed and trains can be rerouted on a different line.  Then there's not much you can do when non-pre-planned changes from express to local or local to express are announced over the PA system on the train.

Answer (score 1):

Both of those sound like poor solutions. You almost certainly won't get a GPS trace in a subway. And the 2nd way sounds like it will be inaccurate enough to make the app useless.

Answer (score 1):

Read carefully Falmarri's answer. He's completely right, although he didn't give you an answer. Let me try then...

If the routes have no many curves, it will be easier: you just have to hardcode the latitude and longitude of each station, and then, calculating the position of the user will be straightforward (just a little of math and that's it). If the routes have curves, then you have more work to do but it's basically the same.

You will probably want to use a way to know the distance between the current location and the station location. You could use some of the existing algorithms, for instance the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).